# change string array content with function in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, replace

So I am really new to C programming and trying to replace a string to a date from a file i read and then write it to an other file.
But the problem is that when i write it into the file the string remains the same.

What I want is to read this from a file:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--#include file=”date”-->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Output file

```
<html>
<head>
Sat Nov 3 14:43:53 2012
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error: passing argument 1 in date_change from incompatible pointer type

Code

//System date replacement function

```
void *date_change(char** s, char* str, char* date){

    static char buffer[4096];
    char *p;

    if(!(p = strstr(*s, str)))  // <!--#echo var=\"date\"--> find this
       return *s;

    strncpy(buffer, *s, p-*s); //
    buffer[p-*s] = '\0';

    sprintf(buffer+(p-*s), "%s%s", date, p+strlen(str));

    return buffer;
}
```

//main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int f;

    f = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    if(errno != 0){
        perror("Hiba");
        exit(1);
    }

    //read from file
    char c[1000];
    while(read(f,&c, 1000)){

    }
```

// --------------------------------//
Get the System date and trying to replace it with the date_change function

```
    time_t mytime;
    mytime = time(NULL);
    struct tm *time = localtime(&mytime);
    char date[20];
    strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%c", time); //format time as string

    char* date_str;

    int g = open("data.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0600);

    //should replace all <!--#echo var=\"date\" --> to the system date
    while(date_str = strstr(c, "<!--#echo var=\"date\"-->")){
           date_change(&c, date_str, date);
    }
    write(g, c, strlen(c));

    close(g);
```

// -------------------------------- //

```
    close(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please have a go at using indentation - makes the code easier to read.

Comment: You're not using the value returned from date_change.

Comment: @EdHeal what do you object to in his indentation? It looks fine to me. Not the exact style I would use, but not wonky either.

Comment: You have some problems, one of them is that you don't define <unistd.h> for read()

Comment: @mah - There is no indentation at all. The code in between braces should be indented to make it readable (easier to see when if statements start and end, ditto for while loops.

Comment: @EdHeal I think it must be something strange on your end -- unless it's something strange on mine that shows 4 spaces of indentation with appropriate additional-4-spacing nesting inside subblocks.

Comment: @mah - Does not work using IE. Just tried Firefox - ok. Perhaps they are tabs?

Comment: Just tried an edit - yes they are tabs. IE does not like tabs.

Comment: @Vaner - You need to convert the tabs to spaces for it to work with IE. It is ok with Firefox.

Comment: `perror("Hiba");` - just a last piece of advice: it's idiomatic to use English error messages. We all know that Hungarian is awesome, but anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read it line by line since you are using a text file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<time.h>

//System date replacement function



void *date_change(char* s, const char* str, const char* date) {

   static char new_line[2000];
   static char new_line2[2000];
   //should replace all <!--#echo var=\"date\" --> to the system date
   char *date_str = strstr(s,str);
   if ( date_str == NULL )
   {
      return s;
   }

   int prefix_length = date_str - s;
   strncpy(new_line,s,prefix_length);
   new_line[prefix_length] = '\0';
   strcat(new_line,date);
   strcat(new_line,s + prefix_length + strlen(str));
   strcpy(new_line2,new_line);
   while ( ( date_str = strstr(new_line,str) ) != NULL)  
   {
      prefix_length = date_str - new_line;
      strncpy(new_line2,new_line,prefix_length);
      new_line2[prefix_length] = '\0';
      strcat(new_line2,date);
      strcat(new_line2,new_line + prefix_length + strlen(str));
      strcpy(new_line,new_line2);
   }

   return new_line2;
}
//main

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   (void) argc;
   FILE *f;

   f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   if(errno != 0)
   {
      perror("Hiba");
      exit(1);
   }
   // --------------------------------
   // Get the System date and trying to replace it with the date_change function
   time_t mytime;
   mytime = time(NULL);
   struct tm *time = localtime(&mytime);
   char date[50];
   strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%c", time); //format time as string

   FILE *g = fopen("data.txt", "w");
   //read from file
   char c[1000];
   //const char *search_string = "<!--#echo var=\"date\" -->";
   const char *search_string = "<!--#include file=”date” -->";
   while(  fgets(c,sizeof(c),f) > 0  ){
      char *new_line = date_change(c, search_string, date);
      fputs(new_line, g);
   }

   fclose(g);
   fclose(f);
}
```

input file:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--#include file="date"--> <p>this is important</p><!--#include file="date"--> the end
</head>
<body>
</body>
<!--#include file="date"-->
</html>
<!--#include file="date"--> <!--#include file="date"--> <!--#include file="date"--> <!--#include file="date"-->
```

output file:

```
<html>
<head>
Sat Nov  3 10:22:06 2012 <p>this is important</p>Sat Nov  3 10:22:06 2012 the end
</head>
<body>
</body>
Sat Nov  3 10:22:06 2012
</html>
Sat Nov  3 10:22:06 2012 Sat Nov  3 10:22:06 2012 Sat Nov  3 10:22:06 2012 Sat Nov  3 10:22:06 2012
```

Comment: still write the original content to the date.txt and does not replace what should

Comment: @Vaner It works for me. Make sure that the string value in the C program exactly matches the value in your file. Is the line that you posted identical to what is in the file? Try it with the lines that I posted above as input.

Comment: @Vaner What you just posted doesn't match what you put in your question. You have a space after "date" in your question (and I used that in my data and program) and you just wrote above a line without a space after "date".

Comment: i updated the question post. The input file looks as it is. But even if it the input file would be 1 line the include=date should be replaced.

Comment: yeah i double checked that to match in the file and your version of the program. Still doesn't work. Writes the original input to the new file.

Comment: @Vaner Works for me. Don't know what is happening on your computer. Can't help on this end.

Comment: ok now it works. I had to escape the " character in the  `const char *search_string = "<!--#include file=\"date\" -->";`

Comment: Oh, I see why it worked for me and not you. If you look at your text above your quote marks around "date" are not straight up and down. They are leaning to the right (posh quotes, or right-double-quotes). When I copied them into Emacs they stayed like that, both in the program and in the input data file I made, so I didn't need to escape them. But yeah, if they are regular " they need to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now i just should figure it out how to write it back to the same file instead of a new :D

Comment: what if i have the string i want to replace it multiple times?

Comment: @Vaner That will do more than one line in the file. If you mean that HTML comment is on a line twice, then it would require a loop inside date_change(). Could there be two replacements in the same line?

Comment: there could be an other comment after 1 sure.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not trying to modify the buffer that was passed into it. Instead, you've created a static array that you are writing into, and you're then returning that static array (without  actually looking at the return value).

Comment: Either change your date_changed() function to send your changes back to the original buffer, or change your write() statement to write out the buffer returned by date_changed() [which would also require you assign that function's return to a variable].

Comment: and i get error passing argument 1 in date_change from incompatible pointer type

Comment: @Vader Updated for multiple on one line.